# Excel online graph not behaving as it should

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to make a line graph in excel, but when i select this whole table instead of first collum of numbers being on x and second on y this happens and i cant find any way to change it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an XY scatter plot instead of a line chart, either with straight or smoothed lines, depending on your needs:
[image: Insert > Charts > Scatter > Scatter with straight lines]

Comment: Thank you so much, i was losing my mind thinking my excel is broken.